# DHCP when you have both layer 3 and switch ports

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I have the following config:

```
ip dhcp pool Vlan10
  network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
  default-router 192.168.1.1

interface GigabitEthernet0/0
  !

interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
  encapsulation dot1Q 10
  ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
  ip nat inside
  description TrunkToSwitch

int FastEthernet0/0
  switchport access vlan 10
```

DHCP doesn't give IP to the PC connected to int f0/0. I cannot use the switch because from g0/0 because it's on another building. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's there on the router. I have edited the post now.

Comment: You are confusing switch and router interfaces. For the switch interface, you need an SVI. That will create the layer-3 interface for the VLAN. You are putting the layer-3 address on a specific router interface, not the VLAN for the switch module.

Comment: Remember that layer-3 bounds layer-2, so layer-2 frames from your external switch cannot cross the layer-3 interface in the router to reach the switch module in the router. The router is _not_ like a layer-3 switch; it is two separate devices (router and switch) in a single box, and the interfaces are either router interfaces, or they are switch interfaces. You can connect two switches together at layer-2, but not through a layer-3 interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of configuring the IP address on the gigabit interface, create a SVI VLAN10 with the IP address on it and make the gigabit interface an access interface in VLAN 10. Now, your fast Ethernet interface isn’t able to reach the gateway IP since it’s configured on another interface.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
  switchport
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10
  description TrunkToSwitch

interface FastEthernet0/0
  switchport access vlan 10

interface VLAN10
  ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
  ip nat inside
```

Comment: The g0/0 is going to a switch. How would it negotiate a trunk if I remove the subinterface?

Comment: You’re mixing up layers. You can still make it a trunk, don’t make it a routed interface. I edited my configuration example to illustrate this.

Comment: @user36337, if you want to trunk that way, then you use a switch module interface, not a router interface. Do not confuse the router and switch interfaces, otherwise you end up with problems like this.

Comment: g0/0 is not a layer 2 interface. I cannot use switchport on it.

Comment: Did you issue a `switchport` command to put in in layer 2 mode?

Comment: @user36337, that is a router interface. That is what I am trying to explain; do not confuse the router interfaces with the switch interfaces in your device. It has a switch module that is conceptually a switch connected to your router via SVIs as the layer-3 interfaces. If you want the switch module to connect to other switches via layer-2 (a VLAN), then you must use a switch interface, not a router interface. If the internal switch module is separated from the other switches by a layer-3 interface, then it cannot share VLANs with the other switches (its VLAN 10 is a different VLAN 10).

Comment: Thank you, @TeunVink. That clears up everything for me. Can you post a config that allows me to use the g0/0 as a trunk? I have removed the sub-interface but I still can't use "switchport" command the main interface. I want to have a Gigabit link with my switch.

Comment: I had already edited my post. If that doesn't work, please read @RonMaupin's post carefully. If you cannot put the gigabit port in switched mode, there's nothing you can do to get this to work the way you want to.